# How do I use ActiveXObject in Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, firefox, activex, greasemonkey

I tried:

```
function AddEmotion(strUrl)
{
    try
    {
        var cpAdder = new ActiveXObject("QQCPHelper.CPAdder");

        if (strUrl != "")
        {   
                cpAdder.AddCustomEmotion(strUrl);
        }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert("error");
    }
}
```

in Firefox Greasemonkey, but it returns an error.

How do I use `new ActiveXObject` in Greasemonkey?
Thank you ^_^ My friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use ActiveX from Greasemonkey, because [**you cannot use ActiveX from javascript in Firefox**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/activex) (Or any sane browser, thank God!).
There used to be some, very dicey, add-ons for Firefox that allegedly provided support, but [there is nothing safe that works with recent/current versions of Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=ActiveX&platform=windows).

Now, you might possibly be able to write your own Firefox extension or plugin for this, but I recommend that you **find a better way to do whatever it is you are trying to do**, that does not use ActiveX in any manner.